# How to redirect url request to localhost with specific port

Tags: networking

How to redirect

**artist.org:80** to **localhost:9999**

modifying hostfile is not enough because it doesn't allow to configure port

Answer (score 0):

You can use IPTables, [Here](http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-redirecting-network-traffic-a-new-ip-using-iptables) is a link regarding how to go about doing so